# Why do case class companion objects extend FunctionN?

Tags: scala, case-class, companion-object

When you create a case class, the compiler creates a corresponding companion object with a few of the case class goodies: an `apply` factory method matching the primary constructor, `equals`, `hashCode`, and `copy`.

Somewhat oddly, this generated object extends FunctionN.

```
scala> case class A(a: Int)                                 
defined class A

scala> A: (Int => A)
res0: (Int) => A = <function1>
```

This is only the case if:

- There is no manually defined companion object
- There is exactly one parameter list
- There are no type arguments
- The case class isn't abstract.

Seems like this was [added](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/changeset/13719) about two years ago. The latest incarnation is [here](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Unapplies.scala?rev=21944#L136).

Does anyone use this, or know why it was added? It increases the size of the generated bytecode a little with static forwarder methods, and shows up in the `#toString()` method of the companion objects:

```
scala> case class A()
defined class A

scala> A.toString
res12: java.lang.String = <function0>
```

**UPDATE**

Manually created objects with a single `apply` method are not automatically considered as `FunctionN`:

```
object HasApply {
  def apply(a: Int) = 1
}
val i = HasApply(1)

// fails
//  HasApply: (Int => Int)
```

Comment: That's a good question. Maybe it's so you can write something like: `List(1,2) map A`? I use this from time to time.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The reason why case class companion objects implement FunctionN is that before, case classes generated a class and a factory method, not a companion object. When we added extractors to Scala it made more sense to turn the factory method into a full companion object with apply and unapply methods. But then, since the factory method did conform to FunctionN, the companion object needed to conform, too.

[Edit] That said, it would make sense to have companion objects show as their own name, not as "function"

Comment: Ah, backwards compatibility, with some help from the uniform access principle. In that context, it makes sense. I've lodged an enhancement request to prettify the `toString` of these: https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/3579

Answer (score 11):

Well, given that `target.apply(a1, a2, a3 ... aN)` in Scala:

1. can be sugared by `target(a1, a2, a3 ... aN)`
2. is the method which needs to be implemented by `FunctionN`

it seems natural that a companion object:

```
object MyClass {
  def apply(a1 : A1, ... aN: AN) = new MyClass(a1, ..., aN)
}
```

is really:

```
object MyClass extends FunctionN[A1, ... , AN, MyClass]{
  def apply(a1 : A1, ... aN: AN) = new MyClass(a1, ..., aN)
}
```

So the addition seems to be natural to me (I'm not sure why it seems "odd" to you?). As to whether it actually *added* anything; well, that is for someone smarter than me!

Answer (score 11):

Aside from oxbow_lakes's reply about the naturalness of it, it can often be useful to have constructors available as first-class functions, particularly in conjunction with Scala collections higher-order functions. For (a trivial) example,

```
scala> case class Foo(i : Int)
defined class Foo

scala> List(1, 2, 3) map Foo   
res0: List[Foo] = List(Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3))
```

Comment: `xs map Foo.apply` is only marginally less convenient.

Answer (score 5):

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.8.0.RC3 (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.6.0_20).

scala> case class CC3(i: Int, b: Boolean, s: String)
defined class CC3

scala> CC3
res0: CC3.type = <function3>

scala> CC3.apply(1, true, "boo!")
res1: CC3 = CC3(1,true,boo!)

scala> CC3(1, true, "boo!")
res2: CC3 = CC3(1,true,boo!)
```

Comment: Well, the syntactic sugar of omitting the name of the `apply` is available regardless of whether or not the receiver extends `FunctionN`.