# Curried case class constructor on companion

Tags: scala, currying, case-class, companion-object

When defining a case class, the default companion object has nice `curried` method to get a curried version of the case class constructor:

```
scala> case class Foo(a: String, b: Int)
defined class Foo

scala> Foo.curried
res4: String => (Int => Foo) = <function1>
```

However, as soon as I define an explicit companion object, this method disappears:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

case class Foo(a: String, b: Int)
object Foo {}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Foo
defined module Foo

scala> Foo.curried
<console>:9: error: value curried is not a member of object Foo
              Foo.curried
```

I can get it back like so:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

case class Foo(a: String, b: Int)
object Foo { def curried = (Foo.apply _).curried }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Foo
defined module Foo

scala> Foo.curried
res5: String => (Int => Foo) = <function1>
```

However, I'd like to know why it disappears when defining an explicit companion (eg. in contrast to `apply`)?

(Scala 2.9.2)

Comment: Maybe the synthetic companion extends Function2 and gets curried from there? Then perhaps you could do it as well.

Comment: Don't know why it's missing, but as a workaround `(Foo(_,_)).curried` has the same effect

Comment: There's a related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3049368/334519)—not exactly a duplicate, so I won't flag as such—with a fairly authoritative accepted answer.

Comment: @MichałPolitowski Indeed, explicitly extending Function2 does the trick.

Comment: @TravisBrown Thanks for the link, missed that one.

Comment: So, as I understand from @Martin Odersky answer, it was made for backwards compatibility, am I right? I also checked, `Scala 2.10.0-M7` behaves the same.

Comment: You can also get to the apply method explicitly, instead of through the Foo() sugar.  So, `(Foo.apply _).curried` gets it.

Answer (score 2):

Scalac create a default companion for each `case class`. The default companion implements `scala.Function`*n*.

When you define an explicit companion, Scalac will merge the explicit companion with default one.

If you want to invoke `curried`, you must let your explicit companion implements `Function2`. Try:

```
case class Foo(a: String, b: Int)
object Foo extends ((String, Int) => Foo) {
  def otherMethod = "foo"
}
```