# Case Class without Parameters

Tags: scala

The Scala Docs on [object](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/singleton-objects.html) comment:

> In fact, a case class with no type parameters will by default create a singleton object of the same name, with a [Function*](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function1.html) trait implemented.

What does the `with a Function* trait implemented` mean?

Comment: `Function*`, meaning any of the `Function1` or `Function2` traits, I assume

Answer (score 6):

`*` is the cardinality of the case class; that is, the number of arguments it takes.

Putting it together:

```
case class Foo(a: Int, b: Long)
```

Represents code that looks like this:

```
class Foo(val a: Int, val b: Long) 

object Foo extends Function2[Int,Long,Foo] {
   def apply(a: Int, b: Long): Foo = new Foo(a,b)
}
```

The above code is not complete, case class creates a lot of other helper functions like pretty printing, unapply for pattern matching, structural equality tests, etc.

Comment: The question did ask about the no-parameter case, though

Comment: Yea, if the case class is like `case class Foo[A,B](a: A, b: B)` then things get a bit more complicated. I believe with parameters there, they mean type parameters and not value arguments.

Comment: So  `case class A()` would extend `Function0[A]`?

Comment: yes, but I think this goes beyond just 2.11. How far back is hard to say, but 2.10, 2.11, 2.12 should behave very similarly.

Comment: @KevinMeredith To be accurate, it will create byte code that would have been the same as if there was an `object A extends Function0[A]` implementation in your code.

Comment: Perhaps other folks are curious why case classes extend `Function` - http://stackoverflow.com/q/3049368/409976.

Comment: There's an issue around explicit object https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4808 and a recent issue around mixing in Serializable too. Maybe they'll rethink how companion generation works?